# How to find the cpu topology in go language?

Tags: go

So I want to use cpu topology in go language. By topology, I mean, NUMA topology. Is there any package out there to do that? Or may be, a package that returns cpu topology, and I can modify on top of that to return NUMA topology.

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it to be cross platform? You could parse /proc/cpuinfo on linux.

This individual seems to have [a start on getting CPU](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/tree/master/cpu) topology.

Comment: I actually want to parse the output of "numactl -H", but I don't know where to start, can you help me with that?

Comment: I am afraid NUMA is beyond my knowledge at this point. It does appear that what you are looking for _may_ reside in `/sys/devices/system/node/node*` i.e. `/sys/devices/system/node/node0/numastat` and other locations under `/sys/devices/system/node/node*`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured it out. :)